# Resolve "Type 'DefaultArgs' does not satisfy the constraint 'RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation'" error

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, cls

I'm trying to use nestjs-cls library with prisma, so I installed "@nestjs-cls/transactional-adapter-prisma" library to make transactional queries on the db.

but when I tried to build the project it gives me this error:
`Type 'DefaultArgs' does not satisfy the constraint 'RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation'`

So the problem from the library itself... the location of the error in a such file in the lib

```js
export declare class TransactionalAdapterPrisma implements TransactionalAdapter<PrismaClient, PrismaTransactionalClient, PrismaTransactionOptions> {
    connectionToken: any;
    constructor(options: {
        prismaInjectionToken: any;
    });
    optionsFactory: (prisma: PrismaClient) => {
        wrapWithTransaction: (options: PrismaTransactionOptions, fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>, setClient: (client?: PrismaTransactionalClient) => void) => Promise<any>;
        getFallbackInstance: () => PrismaClient<import(".prisma/client").Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, never, import("@prisma/client/runtime/library").DefaultArgs>;
    };
}
```

The error in the third parameter of `getFallbackInstance()`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?